# Need event to update quote item while creating an order from admin

Tags: magento2, admin, quote

Can someone tell me an event for updating quote items while creating an order from admin?

Comment: sales_model_service_quote_submit_before try this

Comment: @RkRathod thanks for guiding me but this event is not working. Do you have any other suggestion.

Comment: let me check and let you know

Comment: checkout_cart_product_add_after is working for frontend but I need same for backend. Please suggest.

Comment: `updating quote item while creating order from admin` when you click on **Submit Order** button`.

Comment: @AmitBera I want to add some information in additional_options of quote_item_option table while adding item to quote while creating order from backend. For this purpose I need an event that called after adding item in quote from backend.